How can I use the AWS CLI to match the number of objects mentioned in the AWS web UI in my S3 bucket?
I have an AWS S3 bucket s3://mybucket/. Bucket versioning is enabled (screenshot).
The AWS console web UI indicates that the S3 bucket has 355,524 objects:

How can I use the AWS CLI to match the number of objects mentioned in the AWS web UI in my S3 bucket?

I tried the following commands.
Command 1:
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/ --recursive --summarize --human-readable

outputs:
[Long list of items with their sizes]
Total Objects: 279847
Total Size: 30.8 TiB

Command 2:
aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket | wc -l

outputs 3078321.
Command 3 (mostly adapted from AlexD):
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket mybucket | wc -l

outputs 4508382.

Commands by seligman99 using the JMESPath query language to parse AlexD's command
 output:
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket example --query 'DeleteMarkers[] | length(@)'

+
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket example --query 'Versions[] | length(@)'

=  the number of objects mentioned in the AWS web UI in my S3 bucket.
In this case, 37812 + 317712 = 355,524.

Ah yes! Counting the number of lines in a JSON file does not count the actual number of elements it contains. It's good that you managed to get the numbers to match!
